# I want to import my related product by them tags

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Thats my HomeViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GymInternetShop.ViewModels.Home
{
    public class HomeIndexViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<GymInternetShop.Models.DomainModels.Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GymInternetShop.Models.DomainModels.Product> Products { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GymInternetShop.Models.DomainModels.Product> Papoular { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GymInternetShop.Models.DomainModels.Product> SameProduct { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GymInternetShop.Models.DomainModels.Product> BestSellersProducts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

i wanna use `public IEnumerable<GymInternetShop.Models.DomainModels.Product>  SameProduct { get; set; }` in my HomeIndexViewModel to show Related post on my bottom View Page.

Thats My Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowProducts(string productName , string tags)
    {

        ProductRepository blProduct = new ProductRepository();
        var model = new GymInternetShop.ViewModels.Home.HomeIndexViewModel();
        model.SameProduct = blProduct.Select().Where(p => p.Tags == tags);
        List<Product> src = blProduct.Where(p => p.Url.Trim() == productName.Trim()).ToList();
        if (src.Any())
        {
            return View(src);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
```

i created that controller for when i push on Details Product Button i Redirect To 
My `ShowProduct`View Model and i can See my Product details,
My problem is here:i want Create a Div in Bottom of My `ShowProduct`View Model to   showing Related Post, i want select my Related post with Them Tags in My Sql

and thats my `ShowProduct` View Model:

```
@model IEnumerable<GymInternetShop.Models.DomainModels.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowProducts";
}

<div class="container">
    <h2 >Product Details</h2>
    <div class="separator"></div>
</div>



                                                 //Note: Here i show My Details Product And Thats Work!
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="container" dir="rtl">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="container-fliud">
            <div class="wrapper row">

                <div class="preview col-md-6">

                    <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="pic-1"><img src="/Files/UploadImages/@item.Image" /></div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-2"><img src="/Files/UploadImages/@item.Image" /></div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-3"><img src="/Files/UploadImages/@item.Image" /></div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-4"><img src="/Files/UploadImages/@item.Image" /></div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-5"><img src="/Files/UploadImages/@item.Image" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

                                                    // note: I want to make a Foreach Here and Select my Related Post Where My post Tags looklike My Above product Tags
```

Comment: I explained that
i wanna make a foreach in bottom of my ViewModel and select my product with same tags ,looklike my Details product Tags(Related Post)
but idk how to send my Details product Tags to my controller :(

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing I mean you have the same product list just bind that on the view.